# how to copy a linux mint apt mirror

Tags: mirroring, linux-mint, apt

I have a linux mint install that will be placed on a private network without internet access.  Is it possible to download an Apt mirror for Mint and place in on a server in the private network so that I can install from that server?  If so, how do I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the simplest ways is to use apt-cacher for debian-based systems, if the number of servers is not that large.

http://www.debuntu.org/book/export/html/119

apt-mirror will create full mirror, if apt-cacher is not sufficient.